# Javascript не хочет работать с Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

На форме ввода выполняю проверку введенного значения cost. Но запуске скрипт не может найти форму вводу input01.

Вот так все работает:

```html
<form name="form01" th:method="POST" th:action="@{/add-car/new}" th:object="${carEntity}">
    <input type="text" name="input01">
    ...
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="check()">Save</button>
</form>
<script>
    function check() {
        let inputVal = document.forms["form01"]["input01"].value;
        // Все OK!!!
        // ....
    }
</script>
```

А вот так нет:

```html
<form name="form01" th:method="POST" th:action="@{/add-car/new}" th:object="${carEntity}">
    <input type="text" name="input01" th:field="*{cost}">
    ...
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="check()">Save</button>
</form>
<script>
    function check() {
        let inputVal = document.forms["form01"]["input01"].value;
        // Здесь происходит ошибка
        // Where Error:
        // "Uncaught TypeError: document.forms.form01.input01 is undefined"
        // ...
    }
</script>
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в использовании

```
th:field="*{cost}"
```

`th:field` не только проставляет значение (атрибут `value`),
но и название поля (атрибут `name`)
При этом, если атрибут `name` был проставлен, то он заменяется.

Соответственно `th:field="*{cost}"` заменил  `name="input01"` на  `name="cost"`

Соответственно в `JavaScript` необходимо обращаться к данному элементу следующим образом:

```js
let inputVal = document.forms["form01"]["cost"].value;
```